# How to cancel a running network request in redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, redux-saga

I have a saga:

```
function* sagaOne() {
   yield call(apiOne);
   yield call(apiTwo);
   yield call(apiThree);
}

function* sagaTwo() {
   try {
      yield all(users.map((user) => call(sagaOne, user));
      yield put(successAction);
   } catch (err) {
     yield put(errAction);
   }
}

function* sagaThree() {
   const task = yield fork(sagaTwo);
   yield take(CancelAction);
   yield cancel(task);
}
```

My problem is - when `sagaThree` fires, it forks `sagaTwo`. If I dispatch cancel the action and `sagaOne` is already in a deeper state - `apiOne` call already resolved and `apiTwo` started, the whole request is not canceled.

### Question: how to properly cancel a "deeper", "nested" task (sagaOne), when it's already at 2nd yield or 3rd?

Summing up: cancellation works only if I cancel the task immediately after start and none of the `apiTwo` hasn't started yet. If it goes deeper, the cancellation doesn't work and every call inside every `sagaOne` resolves.

Comment: You're asking how to cancel the api call? It depends on how api call implemented. Is it fetch, xhr or maybe some library like axios?

Comment: Canceling of the sagas works fine, see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions62529072saga-watcher-not-calling-saga-worker-n3h14?file=/src/sagas/root-saga.js ... if you are talking about the API request itself, once the API is called, the request will finish. That is a browser thing, not saga thing.

Comment: @MartinKadlec not accurate, you can actually cancel api request once saga is cancelled. How to do it depends on what is "api request"

Comment: @AlekseyL. it's a POST request. How to cancel it?

Comment: Please add sample code for api call, as mentioned above - it depends on how you do it

Comment: @AlekseyL. Huh it's just some axios request, lets say `const apiOne = () => axios.post();`

Answer (score 1):

> For functions which return Promise results, you can plug your own cancellation logic by attaching a `[CANCEL]` to the promise

More info on cancelling redux-saga tasks [here](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#canceltask).

So we need to enrich promise returned by axios with a method which will be called by redux-saga upon cancelation and will cancel outgoing xhr request. [Here](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) you can find relevant axios documentation.

OK, let's apply this to our api call:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { CANCEL } from 'redux-saga'

const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;

const apiOne = () => {
  const source = CancelToken.source();
  const promise = axios.post('url', {
    cancelToken: source.token
  });

  promise[CANCEL] = () => source.cancel();
  return promise;
};
```

Now once `sagaOne` is cancelled the api call will be cancelled as well (if it wasn't completed yet of course).

---

This is the basic idea. You can extract common logic into wrapper or maybe adapter, so you don't need to do it in each api function. You can also create a cancel token by passing an executor function to the `CancelToken` constructor.